# Customize org-babel latex template when evaluating a source block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm using latex source blocks to generate images with org-babel using `:results file` as in the example below

```bash
#+begin_src latex :results file graphics :file myplot.pdf :fit yes
\LaTeX
#+end_src
```

When evaluating this block I get

```bash
#+RESULTS:
[[file:myplot.pdf]]
```

and the file `myplot.pdf` has "rendered" latex code.

This works quite well with tikz and pgfplots to create figures or plots that are properly included as images when the document is exported. However, the fonts in my plots created like this do not match the rest of the document when the whole org file is exported to PDF, since the main document and the plots are generated with different latex classes. I'd like to customize the template used by org-mode that surrounds the code inside the `#+begin_src` `#+end_src` block to use my customized class.

More specifically, when a latex code block like the one above is evaluated, org will create a temporary file containing something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}

WHAT IS IN MY org-latex-default-packages-alist VARIABLE

\pagestyle{empty}             % do not remove
% The settings below are copied from fullpage.sty
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.54cm}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\LaTeX
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

where my code is inside the `preview` environment (preview is added by the `:fit yes` header). How can I change this template to use a different latex class? The ideal case would be something similar to the `#+LATEX_CLASS:mycustomclass` header that can be added to the main document. In order words, is it possible to choose one of the classes in `org-latex-classes` when evaluating a latex code block?

Comment: Although it's far from convenient, you can customize `org-format-latex-header`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I only needed to change the "documentclass" value in the the string stored in `org-format-latex-header` to my custom latex class. I  wish I could be set with a local file or directory variable, but this is good enough.